# UIColor dark mode backwards compatibility

Tags: swift, uicolor, swiftui

I got lots of labels which have the color set to black. With the upcoming of dark mode, they should switch to an other color, since else they will be invisible. With `SwiftUI`, I thought this goes automatically when setting the `Color` property to `primary`.

Is there such thing for `UIColor`? This label will be invisible in dark mode:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)

        label.text = "some text"
        label.textColor = .black

        view.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

I can make lots and lots and lots of if statements to handle it, but is there an automatic `UIColor` property which will switch to the appropriate state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at [`UIColor.label`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173131-label).

Comment: Cool! And https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173140-systembackground reverses white with black :)